# No resolvers provided! nestjs-i18n won't workt properly

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-i18n

**Package version:** 10.2.1

**Error:**
[I18nService] No resolvers provided! nestjs-i18n won't workt properly, please follow the quick-start guide: https://nestjs-i18n.com/quick-start

**Code:**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ cache: true, isGlobal: true }),
    I18nModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        fallbackLanguage: 'en',
        loaderOptions: {
          path: join(__dirname, 'i18n'),
          watch: configService.get('NODE_ENV') === 'development',
        },
        logging: configService.get('NODE_ENV') === 'development', // REVIEW: Is this necessary?
        resolvers: [AcceptLanguageResolver],
      }),
    }),
  ],
})
```

Revert to the old version.

Answer (score 2):

**Resolved!**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ cache: true, isGlobal: true }),
    I18nModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      resolvers: [AcceptLanguageResolver],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        fallbackLanguage: 'en',
        loaderOptions: {
          path: join(__dirname, 'i18n'),
          watch: configService.get('NODE_ENV') === 'development',
        },
        logging: configService.get('NODE_ENV') === 'development', // REVIEW: Is this necessary?
      }),
    }),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`resolvers: [AcceptLanguageResolver]`
should put outside the useFactory.